# ldd shows that ELF interpreter is present but I still get a "No such file or directory"

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, elf, glibc, ldd

Recently I struggled porting an existing C++ application onto a new production environment (updated kernel, updated glibc, etc). Even though the output of ldd showed that all my .so were found, including the ELF interpreter, the execution always resulted on a "No such file or directory".

$ ldd my_app

```
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fd41afd6000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fd41ae52000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/libm.so.6 (0x00007fd41ad11000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fd41acf7000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007fd41ab3a000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 => /lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fd4258b5000) <= ELF Interpreter
    libconfig.so.9 => /usr/lib/libconfig.so.9 (0x00007fd41ab2c000)
    libsensors.so.4 => /usr/lib/libsensors.so.4 (0x00007fd41ab1b000)
```

$ file my_app

```
     ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=c8c7eeb2f6bdb96dab7b0cc9ad41aa6e3d610ec7, stripped
```

$ readelf -a my_app | grep "interpreter"

```
  [Requesting program interpreter: /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2]
```

I didn't think my problem had anything to do with the interpreter because of this output of ldd. So I tried all other possible workarounds with no success. After much digging online I encountered a related problem that the solution suggested the creation of a symlink from the application's hard-coded path for the interpreter to the real path one. In my case:

```
  ln -s /lib/ld-2.29.so /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
```

This finally resolved the problem. At the end I was frustrated since I wasn't looking for the real problem and it took me too long to realize it because of the misleading output of ldd.

Why does ldd say that the interpreter is there even though it will not be loaded when you run the binary? Is my interpretation of the use/output of ldd mistaken?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> onto a new production environment

Your new production environment installed `ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` into `/lib` instead of `/lib64`. This is highly unusual and non-standard. Many binaries will fail to run on such a system. Whoever "made" this system, probably made a grave mistake.

> Why does ldd say that the interpreter is there

The way `ldd` works is: it sets an environment variable `LD_TRACE_OBJECTS=1` and invokes the *real* interpreter it was compiled with.

Since your system (erroneously) installed `ld-linux` into `/lib`, `ldd` dutifully invoked `/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`, which *does* exist, and actually told you so.

In general, `ldd` is *not* trustworthy, especially when several versions of GLIBC are installed on a single system.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Ironically, I'm the one who is "making" the system as well. I'm using Yocto to build it and I just checked that the "base_libdir" is set to "/lib64" only on powerpc64 archs, on all other cases it is set to "/lib". I'll look for the reason to why this is so and if I can just change it. "In general, ldd is not trustworthy" -  do you have any other tools to suggest?

Answer (score 2):

In glibc, the dynamic loader `ld.so.` is both used as the program interpreter and as a loaded shared object. `ldd` only displays the latter.  It can find `ld.so` because it is either on the search path or in the `ld.so` cache.  In contrast, when the kernel tries to load the program interpreter, it only uses the exact path specified in the program, so search paths and the like do not apply.

The correct path according to the [ABI manual](https://github.com/hjl-tools/x86-psABI/wiki/X86-psABI) is `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`. If your system does not have that, it does not follow the GNU/Linux x86-64 ABI, which is rather odd.